# SQL: How to select data from this 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables: Project, Company, Address, like below:

### Project

- ProjectID (not nullable)
- CompanyID (not nullable)
- AddressID (nullable)

### Company

- CompanyID (not nullable)
- AddressID (not nullable)

### Address

- AddressID (not nullable)
- Street

the rule is, if a project has an AddressID, then take the Street directly from the Address.
If not, then through the Company to get the Address and the Street.

Can I solve this in one SQL query?

Comment: What should happen if a project has a matching `AddressID`, but the `Street` for that `ID` is `null`? Should the `null` be shown because the project has a matching address, or should it fall back to the company?

Comment: @Jonny Null should be shown

Comment: @Hamlet actually I don't have a clue, I can only accomplish this with two SQL querys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.ProjectID, p.CompanyID, a.AddressID, a.Street
FROM Project p
INNER JOIN Company c
ON p.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
INNER JOIN Address a
ON ISNULL(p.AddressID, c.AddressID) = a.AddressID
```

`ISNULL` returns `Project.AddressID` if it is not null; if it is null then it returns c.AddressID

Answer (score 1):

Give something like this a try:

```
select p.ProjectID, coalesce(a1.Street, a2.Street)
from   Project p inner join
       Company c on p.CompanyID = c.CompanyID left join
       Address a1 on p.AddressID = a1.AddressID left join
       Address a2 on c.AddressID = a2.AddressID
```

If a1.Street is null (the address listed on the project) then a2.Street (the address from the company) will be returned

Comment: this doesn't work, but looks like in the right direction, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.*, case when p.addressid is not null
                 then ap.street
                 else ac.street
            end as street
from project p
left join company c on c.companyid = p.companyid
left join address ap on ap.addressid = p.addressid
left join address ac on ac.addressid = c.addressid
```